# How to install the latest version of Vagrant

Tags: 18.04, vagrant

I have downloaded the vagrant 2.2.9 64 bit setup file from [Downloads | Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html). It is not a .deb file, it does not have any extension so I can not understand how can I install vagrant using this file. It only shows **exec** in green letters in the file icon.

How can I install vagrant in my ubuntu 18.04.4 using this file? Or is there any other way to install the latest version of Vagrant?

Comment: It only says "Vagrant is packaged as an operating-specific package. Run the installer for your system." No specific information.

Comment: Yes it is. But I don't know how to run this installer.

Comment: Yes, it has worked now, thanks. But, shouldn't I also be able to install from the previous setup file as it was also for linux?

Comment: Yes, easily...if you know how to expand zipfiles, make files executable, and run install scripts manually. Debian-based systems abandoned all those annoyances 20 years ago when they invented deb packages.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Can you give me a link from where I can learn those?

Comment: The steps required to install from the previous setup file.

Comment: 1) You unzip it (the command depends upon how it's compressed.) 2) You read the README file, in case something important or useful is there (usually yes.) 3) You locate the install script (usually `install.sh` or similar.) 4) Use `chmod +x /path/to/install.sh` to make the script executable. 5) Run /path/to/install.sh to start the install script. 6) Follow the prompts. Well, that's a trip down memory lane....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the Debian package (not the generic Linux zipfile)

[image: Debian package, not the Linux zipfile]

2. Look in your Downloads directory for the exact filename. Mine was `vagrant_2.2.9_x86_64.deb` your filename may vary.
3. Install. Recall that the file is in the Downloads directory, and use the correct filename. On mine it's: `sudo apt install ~/Downloads/vagrant_2.2.9_x86_64.deb`

Answer (score 1):

Automate the process with a simple script below:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
export VERSION=$(curl -s https://api.github.com/repos/hashicorp/vagrant/tags | jq ".[0].name" | cut -c 3-8)
curl -O https://releases.hashicorp.com/vagrant/$VERSION/vagrant_{$VERSION}_x86_64.deb
chmod 755 vagrant_$(echo $VERSION)_x86_64.deb
sudo apt install ./\vagrant_$(echo $VERSION)_x86_64.deb
rm -f vagrant_$(echo $VERSION)_x86_64.deb
```

The code will install the latest version of Vagrant.